# Change display format of html input attribute type="date" to European format

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the format showed with the html input attribute type="date" from English format to European format. I only want to display the European format to the user, but not affect the value that goes to the back-end.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: I believe it's automatically handled by the browser

Comment: "from English format to European format" - English more specifically England uses the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Did you mean change to using en-GB locale? Also, English _is_ a European language!